What is the font used in Google's Captcha title?
I haven't been served one of these in a while so I can't just use dev tools to inspect the font. What are the fonts used?


One could examine the HTML/CC to see what font it is. Simply inspect the page via Developer Mode (Chrome) or similar in any browser.

As per the question - I do not currently have a page with a captcha on it.  I guess I must not use sites with recaptcha v2 that often, because I don't get them. Or maybe I tend to seem too human for the sites to bother. Hence my asking here, because (repeating) as I said I do not have access to the html, I have somebody's image.

you should [edit] to rephrase your question to focus on one problem. Do you want to know the font in the image or you want a tool to find fonts in images? Side note: I doubt that there will be a command line tool for that, unless you're talking about chatGPT and the likes.

ok I have edited to rephrase to focus just on what I want at this very second - what is the font used in that image.

Go here https://google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo for a demo captcha, click I'm not a Robot, and then right click the text, and inspect the element in your browser. You should be able to find the font.  By the way it's Roboto

ya know.. I went looking for an automatic way to initiate recatcha (without the need to log into a Google account or anything).. knew there had to be one. I couldn't find it.. nice find @BillyKerr

Google Captcha uses Roboto Regular (font-weight: 400) for the introduction text and Roboto Black (font-weight: 900) for the title

https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto
